# Using virtualenv (or other modules) without admin privileges

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, virtualenv

I am working on a very restricted Windows machine:

- I have python installed and can use it in CMD
- I have connected a special repo with a selection packages where I can safely load libraries just like via pip
- I do not have admin privileges and am unable to download or install any software directly from the internet
- I do have powershell access though
- Sysadmins will not whitelist individual files or programs

**Here is my issue:**
I can install virtualenv and create virtual environments but i cannot activate them in CMD. If I type venv\Scripts\activate it says that it is blocked by group policy. However, if I use powershell I am able to activate (but not create) the virtual environment - but I cannot use python in the powershell. In powershell I get the blocked by group policy error for python itself but not for the virtualenvironment.

Is there some workaround to create virtual environments that i can start in CMD without admin rights? If that is not possible, is there some way to add python to Powershell so that I can work there?

I can see in AppLocker that activate.bat and python.exe are blocked when trying to activate venv in CMD or starting python in powershell respectively.

So far I tried Anaconda, Virtualenv and Pipenv. I receive the group policy error also when trying to start Spyder. If there is some workaround as well to start it without getting blocked by group policy that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you try working with miniconda. For that, go here:

https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

and install Miniconda. It features its own Python install. Then, in the PowerShell, you can create a conda environment using:

```
conda create --name nameofyourenvironment
```

and activate it using:

```
conda activate nameofyourenvironment
```

If this does not work, maybe you should contact the IT person who is responsible for group permissions on your machine...

I hope this will help you.